# Hadoop: Process image files in Python code

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm working on a side project where we want to process images in a hadoop mapreduce program (for eventual deployment to Amazon's elastic mapreduce). The input to the process will be a list of all the files, each with a little extra data attached (the lat/long position of the bottom left corner - these are aerial photos)

The actual processing needs to take place in Python code so we can leverage the Python Image Library. All the Python streaming examples I can find use stdin and process text input. Can I send image data to Python through stdin? If so, how?

I wrote a Mapper class in Java that takes the list of files and saves the names, the extra data, and the binary contents to a sequence file. I was thinking maybe I need to write a custom Java mapper that takes in the sequence file and pipes it to Python. Is that the right approach? If so, what should the Java to pipe the images out and the Python to read them in look like?

In case it's not obvious, I'm not terribly familiar with Java OR Python, so it's also possible I'm just biting off way more than I can chew with this as my introduction to both languages...

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible approaches that I can see:

1. Use both the extra data and the file contents as input to your python program. The tricky part here will be the encoding. I frankly have no idea how streaming works with raw binary content, and I'm assuming that basic answer is "not well." The main issue is that the stdin/stdout communication between processes is very text-based, relying on delimiting input with tabs and newlines, and things like that. You would need to worry about the encoding of the image data, and probably have some sort of pre-processing step, or a custom InputFormat so that you could represent the image as text.
2. Use only the extra data and the file location as input to your python program. Then the program can independently read the actual image data from the file. The hiccup here is making sure that the file is available to the python script. Remember this is a distributed environment, so the files would have to be in HDFS or somewhere similar, and I don't know if there are good libraries for reading files from HDFS in python.
3. Do the java-python interaction yourself. Write a java mapper that uses the [Runtime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) class to start the python process itself. This way you get full control over exactly how the two worlds communicate, but obviously its more code and a bit more involved.